# ColdFusion checkbox processing

Tags: checkbox, coldfusion

I have a question about processing data for lines where checkbox is checked.
When I hit "Submit", I need to end up with as many lines in a table as checked on the form.

[image]

Here is code that populates the form data. Checkbox''s value is unique.

```
<CFLOOP  query = "ship_details">
    <tr bgcolor="#IIf(CurrentRow Mod 2, DE('ffffff'), DE('f8f8f8'))#">
        <TD class="TDC" align="right"><INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="MYCHECKBOX" value="#ship_details.cust_po_nbr#" ID="chkPo" checked></TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.cust_po_nbr#</TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.store_id#</TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.numb_of_cart#</TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.total_qty#</TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.weight#</TD>
        <TD class="TDC">#ship_details.volume#</TD>
        <cfif form.soldto EQ "AMAZON">
            <TD class="TDC"><cfinput name="pallets" type="text" size="10"></TD>
        </cfif>         
    </TR>
</CFLOOP>
```

When I hit "Submit", following query fails.

```
<cfquery name="abc" datasource="#REQUEST.T#">
    insert into T
    values (
      #ship_details.cust_po_nbr#
      ,#pallets#
    )
</cfquery>
```

It''s because values entered into  fields coming over as list:

```
<cfloop list="#MYCHECKBOX#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>#i# - #pallets#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
<cfabort>
```

I see this:

152N0000 - 1,2,5

152N5IKV - 1,2,5

6N8SCRIY - 1,2,5

Comment: What does your browser developer tool say it is sending to the server in the request tab? How many checkboxes values are in there?

Comment: You are looping over this command: <cfinput name="pallets" type="text" size="10">.   This is creating five different input text boxes that all have the same name of 'pallets'.  The way HTML form will handle this is to combine all of the values into one list.  This can be useful but doesn't seem to be your desired outcome.  One way to get around this is to make sure your pallet text inputs all have a unique NAME based on the productID for example.

Comment: Do you know how to loop through a list?

Comment: I know how to loop through a list. I can loop over a list of checked boxes, but the issues is: not every checked line will have a "pallets" value populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is appending or prepending an identifier or index to all of your input names. This way you can connect fields with each other in the controller.

## Simplified example (ugly iteration)

```
<cfloop query="ship_details">
    <input type="checkbox" name="MYCHECKBOX_#ship_details.currentRow#" value="#ship_details.cust_po_nbr#">
    <input type="text" name="pallets_#ship_details.currentRow#">
</cfloop>
```

yields a form submit like

```
{
    "MYCHECKBOX_1": "12345",
    "MYCHECKBOX_3": "12347",
    "pallets_1": "5",
    "pallets_2": "",
    "pallets_3": "7"
}
```

*(row 1 and 3 have been checked - unchecked inputs are not part of a submit)*

which you can connect doing

```
<cfset inputData = []>

<cfset MAX_ROWS = 99>
<cfloop from="1" to="#MAX_ROWS#" index="row">

    <!--- has this row been checked? --->
    <cfif not structKeyExists(FORM, "MYCHECKBOX_#row#")>
        <cfcontinue>
    </cfif>

    <cfset inputData.add({
        "cust_po_nbr": FORM["MYCHECKBOX_#row#"],
        "pallets":     FORM["pallets_#row#"]
    })>

</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#inputData#">
```

and ending up with

```
[
    {
        "cust_po_nbr": "12345",
        "pallets": "5"
    },
    {
        "cust_po_nbr": "12347",
        "pallets": "7"
    }
]
```

### Proper example

Since iterating over an artificial limit is pretty ugly, you can also just extract the checkboxes beforehand by matching against fieldnames

```
<cfset inputData = []>

<cfset checkedRows = reMatchNoCase("\bMYCHECKBOX_[0-9]+\b", FORM.FIELDNAMES)>
<cfloop array="#checkedRows#" index="cbKey">

    <cfset row = listLast(cbKey, "_")>

    <cfset inputData.add({
        "cust_po_nbr": FORM[cbKey],
        "pallets":     FORM["pallets_#row#"]
    })>

</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#inputData#">
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, sorry for delay, but I learned something new.